# Discriminant of a product of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, discriminant, resultant

Let $f$ and $g$ be monic polynomials in $\mathbb Z[x]$.

Then,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{disc} (f\cdot g)
= \operatorname{disc}(f)\cdot \operatorname{disc}(g) \cdot \prod_i\prod_j(a_i-b_j)^2 ,
\end{align}
where the $a_i$ are the roots of $f$ (with multiplicities) and the $b_j$ are the roots of $g$ (with multiplicities).

> It seems that the term $\prod_i\prod_j(a_i-b_j)^2$ is always a square in $\mathbb Z$, but I can't rewrite it to see this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task is equivalent to showing that $\prod_{i,j} (a_i-b_j)$ is an integer.  This follows from the fact that the expression is symmetric in the $a_i$ and symmetric in the $b_j$.

Explicitly, consider the corresponding polynomial $F(x) = \prod_{i,j} (x_i-y_j)$ in $\mathbb Z[x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_n]$, where $m = \deg f, n = \deg g$.  If you treat $F$ as an element of $R[y_1, \ldots, y_n]$, where $R = \Bbb Z[x_1, \ldots, x_m]$, then the result is evidently symmetric, in that any permutation of the $y_j$ merely permutes terms of $F$.

Using the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials), we can rewrite it as a polynomial in the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $y_j$ over $R$.  Note that up to sign these are the coefficients of $g$, and are thus integers.  This means that if we set $y_j = b_j$, we get an element of $\Bbb Z[x_1, \ldots, x_m]$.  This is similarly symmetric in the $x_i$, so we can plug in $x_i = a_i$ and get an integer at the end by the same argument.